# Oracle DISTINCT query with ORDER BY on field not required in resultset

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some data like this in an Oracle table called NAMES

```
| id | name    | language | language_id |
| 1  | Paul    | English  | 4           |
| 1  | Pablo   | Spanish  | 10          |
| 2  | Richard | English  | 4           |
```

i need an sql query that will sort by name, but the query does not need to return the actual name, just the correct order... The problem is that I also need a distinct list of id's

if I do the following SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   ID 
FROM 
   NAMES
WHERE
   language_id in (4,10)
ORDER BY NAME
```

The result in oracle is:

```
| id | 
| 1  | 
| 1  |
| 2  |
```

I'd like just one result to be returned, which is NOT provided by the distinct in this scenario as the name that is included in the `order by` clause is duplicated, so Oracle returns both - I understand this because if there was a bigger list of names Paul and Pablo would appear in different positions in the order, so would not know which one to remove in the distinct

The question is, how can I specify a preferred language id, in the sql query, that would return the record with the preferred language id, in the case where there is multiple results for the same id?

So for this example, the desired query would return:

```
| id | 
| 1  |
| 2  |
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you got it wrong. The first query you wrote wouldn't return *anything*, it is invalid (you can't order by a column that isn't part of the select column list if you're using DISTINCT or aggregates):

```
SQL> with names (id, name, language_id) as
  2    (select 1, 'paul'   ,  4 from dual union all
  3     select 1, 'pablo'  , 10 from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'richard',  4 from dual
  5    )
  6  select distinct id
  7  from names
  8  where language_id In (4, 10)
  9  order by name;
order by name
         *
ERROR at line 9:
ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression


SQL>
```

Why do you care about NAME and want to sort the result by it? What difference does it make? Why not simply

```
SQL> with names (id, name, language_id) as
  2    (select 1, 'paul'   ,  4 from dual union all
  3     select 1, 'pablo'  , 10 from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'richard',  4 from dual
  5    )
  6  select distinct id
  7  from names
  8  where language_id In (4, 10);

        ID
----------
         1
         2

SQL>
```

**[EDIT]**

See if this helps; aggregate first (which means that you'll get DISTINCT values anyway), then sort by MIN_NAME:

```
SQL> with names (id, name, language_id) as
  2    (select 1, 'paul'   ,  4 from dual union all
  3     select 1, 'pablo'  , 10 from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'richard',  4 from dual
  5    ),
  6  inter as
  7    (select id, min(name) min_name
  8     from names
  9     where language_id in (4, 10)
 10     group by id
 11    )
 12  select id
 13  from inter
 14  order by min_name;

        ID
----------
         1
         2

SQL>
```

Comment: Basically, i am working with legacy code - after the id’s are returned in order, a bunch of other queries are fired off to get more data associated with the id’s, and the order of the original query is maintained

Comment: Suppose names (in your example) were (Paul, Xena) (for ID = 1) and Richard (for ID = 2). Distinct ID would still be 1 and 2. What would your ORDER BY return? They are ordered as (Paul, Richard, Xena) which means that IDs are (1, 2, 1). What if all names were Paul? How would you sort that?

Comment: If all results returned with a unique id, then it would not matter to the program if all related ‘name’ values were Paul.  Is there any way i can specify a preferred language_id in the case i find more than one record for the same id? If not, i’ll need to do a big refactor

Comment: That's what I was trying to say - the whole story seems to be kind of *wrong*. Though, before refactoring, see whether code I posted makes sense (I've edited my answer; have a look, please).

Comment: You are absolutely correct, this scenario is far from ideal. I've tried your query and it works for my scenario, thank you for that. I've accepted the answer

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why your first query would return three rows of `1`, `1`, and `2`. That's simply not going to occur. As @Littlefoot points out, it won't execute as written because you can't order by a column you haven't SELECTed. Second, if you eliminate the invalid ORDER BY:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID 
FROM NAMES
WHERE language_id in (4,10)
```

it *will* return

```
ID
2
1
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=04f7dc3c3d37eb8ac4607f35b84de652).

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and working for the records that I have inserted. I have also added the SQL Fiddle link:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/24679a/2

```
select distinct id 
from (
      SELECT id,name
      FROM NAMES
      WHERE language_id in (4,10,11)
      ORDER BY NAME
     ) tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY`, but you need to decide *which* name to `ORDER BY`.  For instance:

```
SELECT ID 
FROM NAMES
WHERE language_id in (4, 10)
ORDER BY MIN(NAME);
```

Ahhh . . . Your question does ask for doing this by language id.  Here is an easy method:

```
SELECT ID 
FROM NAMES
WHERE language_id in (4, 10)
ORDER BY COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN language_id = 4 THEN NAME END),
                  MAX(CASE WHEN language_id = 10 THEN NAME END)
                 )
```

If language "4" exists, then it is used, otherwise 10.